# Generating a sparse matrix given a list of lists with strings

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix

Assume a list of lists with strings as below

```
docs = [["hello", "world", "hello"], ["goodbye", "cruel"]]
```

How does one go about creating a sparse matrix where each row represents a sublist of the above list and each column represents a token string like "cruel" in the sublist.

I looked at the scipy docs [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.html) and some other stackoverflow posts, but, this one is not clear to me.

```
row_idx = 0                                                                                                                                   
col_idx = 0                                                                                                                                   
rows = []                                                                                                                                     
cols = []                                                                                                                                     
vals = []                                                                                                                                     
for doc in tokens_list:                                                                                                                       
    col_idx = 0                                                                                                                               
    for token in doc:                                                                                                                         
        rows.append(row_idx)                                                                                                                  
        cols.append(col_idx)                                                                                                                  
        col_idx = col_idx + 1                                                                                                                 
        vals.append(1)                                                                                                                        
    row_idx = row_idx + 1                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
X = csr_matrix((vals, (rows, cols)))
```

I tried something like above but I have a feeling this isn't right and I can't relate to the examples in scipy documentation.

Comment: What's the expected output?

Comment: Do you have to do it with lists? This is extremely nice, simple, and straightforward with dictionaries!

Comment: @Divakar The actual input is [['isn', 't', 'this', 'movie', 'great'], ['horrible', 'horrible', 'movie']] with the expected output I believe being [[1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1],                                                                                                              [0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0]].

Comment: @Agaidis How is it straightforward with dictionaries?

Comment: I have no idea how its possible for a length 5 list with a length 3 list to map to a 6x2 list. You need to explain what you want better.

Answer (score 1):

I would create a dictionary instead of using lists. Then, you can have a tuple (row, col) as your key and the value would be whatever is contained at that row,col index. You get sparsity by only adding the elements to the dictionary that are not null, 0, etc. in your matrix.

You can also substitute the tuples for lists.

Answer (score 0):

The example on the `csr` docs generates the `csr` attributes directly, `indptr`, `indices` and `data`.  Inputs for `coo` are `row`, `col`, and `data`.  The difference is in the `row` and `indptr`; the other attributes are the same.

At a first glance you are missing the `vocabulary` dictionary.  It's easy to match `row` with item index in the list.  But `col` has to map, somehow, on to a list or dictionary of words.

```
In [498]: docs = [["hello", "world", "hello"], ["goodbye", "cruel", "world"]]
In [499]: indptr = [0]
In [500]: indices = []
In [501]: data = []
In [502]: vocabulary = {}  # a dictionary
In [503]: for d in docs:
     ...: ...     for term in d:
     ...: ...         index = vocabulary.setdefault(term, len(vocabulary))
     ...: ...         indices.append(index)
     ...: ...         data.append(1)
     ...: ...     indptr.append(len(indices))
     ...:     
In [504]: indptr
Out[504]: [0, 3, 6]
In [505]: indices
Out[505]: [0, 1, 0, 2, 3, 1]
In [506]: data
Out[506]: [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
In [507]: vocabulary
Out[507]: {'cruel': 3, 'goodbye': 2, 'hello': 0, 'world': 1}
In [508]: M = sparse.csr_matrix((data, indices, indptr), dtype=int)
In [510]: M
Out[510]: 
<2x4 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int32'>'
    with 6 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
In [511]: M.A
Out[511]: 
array([[2, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 1, 1]])
```

The `coo` inputs would look like:

```
In [515]: Mc = M.tocoo()
In [516]: Mc.row
Out[516]: array([0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1], dtype=int32)
In [517]: Mc.col
Out[517]: array([0, 1, 0, 2, 3, 1], dtype=int32)
```

So the same iteration works, except we record the row number in a `row` list:

```
In [519]: row, col, data = [],[],[]
In [520]: vocabulary = {}
In [521]: for i,d in enumerate(docs):
     ...:     for term in d:
     ...:         index = vocabulary.setdefault(term, len(vocabulary))
     ...:         col.append(index)
     ...:         data.append(1)
     ...:         row.append(i)
     ...:         
In [522]: row
Out[522]: [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1]
In [523]: col
Out[523]: [0, 1, 0, 2, 3, 1]
In [524]: M1 = sparse.coo_matrix((data, (row, col)))
In [525]: M1
Out[525]: 
<2x4 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int32'>'
    with 6 stored elements in COOrdinate format>
In [526]: M1.A
Out[526]: 
array([[2, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 1, 1]])
```

'hello' occurs twice in the first list; all other words occur once, or none.  `vocabulary` has the mapping between word and column indices.

An alternative would make two passes.  The first collects all words and identifies the unique ones - that is, generate `vocabulary` or the equivalent.  The second then builds the matrix.